# Javascript Jquery Json - Displaying Facebook Comments from Graph api

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I have to display all the comments of a page from the json string from the facebook graph as input, exactly like this, but for another website, of course:

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.facebook.com

What I have to do now is to display all the comments in an ordered way, like, for example, the facebook comments plugin do.

I couldn't find any code snippet to do this (is it possible?), so maybe I'm just looking to the wrong direction.

Any clue of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can loop through everything like this and get everything you want

```
$(data).each(function(){
     //do your code here for each 
     //to get a value from your json you can retrieve it like this 
     this.id;
     this.from;
     this.message;
     this.created_time;
     this.comment;//this has more object that you can loop  
     $(this.comment.data).each(function(){
         //here you can do the same as above 
           this.id;
           this.from;
           this.message;
           this.created_time;
     });
});
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: tnx, but do you know how can I handle the paging in that way?

Comment: sorry I dont think I understand, do you mean paging of the comments so to only display a certain number on the page with options to view more??

Comment: Facebook uses paging when there are more than 25 comments in the same page, but I found on the documentation how to do it :)